# IntelliJ IDEA, jbehave support plugin cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jbehave, jbehave-plugin

I've faced with the next problem:

after installing `jbehave support` plugin I can't jump to step declaration in Java.

I've already tried:

1. to uninstall and again install this plugin;
2. to use `jbehave plugin`, but this functionality also didn't work;
3. to create new project and import already existed project in it;
4. to import all project modules again;
5. to restart IntelliJ IDEA few times;
6. to Invalidate Caches/restart(IntelliJ IDEA functionality);
7. to reboot my PC.

My OS: **Windows 7 Professional 64-bit**.

**IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1**

If you need any additional info, please mention which one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: here is what fixed it for me today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35455980/4166508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you should be sure, that those steps have declaration to go to, because it's possible to have steps without it.
2. you successfully build your project(all modules were downloaded and build successfully).
3. your project configured correctly and you added all module dependencies.

In my case it was 2nd option from the list.
After that I can jump to step declaration.

Answer (score 2):

What did it for me was:

1. following this guide for importing the Ant build: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hDxv7jjlPc
2. specifying `src` folder as "Sources":

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

"cannot find declaration to go to" in Intellij with grails

if you find  mentioned issue,
Just go to the 
file --> setting --> language Framework -->grails--> .sdkman  --> ................... grails 3.1.0 like --> ok

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with your "Project Settings", assuming you are using Mac, try the following:

- "cmd + ;" or "File" => "Project Structure" to open "Project Settings"
- Check "Project Settings" => "Project" => "Project SDK"
- Check "Project Settings" => "Modules" => "Dependencies" => "Module SDK"
- Check "Platform Settings" => "SDKs"

All the SDKs settings can be found in "/usr/local/Cellar/..." if you use brew on a Mac.

Then rebuild the project, let IntelliJ does the indexing and restart IntelliJ couple times to make sure the changes have taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add my answer, which can be rare but happened to me, which is conflict of multiple jBehave plugin in existence. the only correct plugin to use is 'jbehave support'. if you have multiple jbehave plugin installed, uninstall/disable the others, then it will just work